# Cannot open package because FileMode or FileAccess value is not valid for the stream C#

Tags: c#, excel, wpf

I'm trying to load an Excel file `(.xlsx)` to a Datagrid in C# using this function, my goal is to load the data to save it later to the database.

```
 public static DataTable GetDataFromExcel(string path, dynamic worksheet)

    {
        //Save the uploaded Excel file.

        
        

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            //Open the Excel file using ClosedXML.
            using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(stream))
            {
                //Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
                IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(worksheet);

                //Create a new DataTable.

                //Loop through the Worksheet rows.
                bool firstRow = true;
                foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
                {
                    //Use the first row to add columns to DataTable.
                    if (firstRow)
                    {
                        foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value.ToString()))
                            {
                                dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        firstRow = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        DataRow toInsert = dt.NewRow();
                        foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells(1, dt.Columns.Count))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                toInsert[i] = cell.Value.ToString();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {

                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                        dt.Rows.Add(toInsert);
                    }
                }
                return dt;
            }
        }
        }
```

Unfortunately, I got this exception:

> Cannot open package because FileMode or FileAccess value is not valid for the stream

how can I avoid this exception from throwing?

Update :

```
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    //Static File From Base Path...........
                    //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "TestExcel.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
                    //Dynamic File Using Uploader...........
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(txtFilePath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); ;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;

// I have used excelSheet as workSheet
```

Comment: Why do you need Write permissions or OpenOrCreate?

Comment: I just added it now as a solution from StackOverflow question

Comment: `FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write` seem to be a weird combination.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed them to `FileMode.Open` and to `FileAccess.Read` but I got another exception : `The best overloaded method match for 'ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.Worksheet(string)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: The last error is a compile-time error, what have you changed? Why is the argument `worksheet` in your method of type `dynamic`?

Comment: See the update please

Comment: Your edit completely changes the problem. It is unclear what are you using.

Comment: Why you unvote my answer??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236948/discussion-between-csharp-devloper31-and-steeeve).

Answer (score 0):

I always use this (C# 9.0):

```
FileStream fileStream = new(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Also allows me to read it while is opened.

If you're not using a recent version of C# then use:

```
var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Comment: Also to read faster, I use EPPlus, is really fast!